# WSO2:AM: populating organization changes without Hazelcast

Tags: wso2-api-manager, hazelcast, wso2

We are running WSO2-AM 2.6 multi tenant cluster that has two kinds of nodes

- Full profile node (publisher, store, KM, etc..)
- Gateway worker nodes

Sharing information b/w publisher and gateways is done using EFS.

So far we were working with Hazelcast enabled, but we prefer to have Hazelcast disabled as it is giving us a lot of pain in production, and we understand that in WSO2 2.x it is not mandatory to have it enabled.

We tested our system with the following setting:

```
<clustering class="org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent" enable="false">
```

Everything was running ok, except for one side effect that we noticed: that it takes a long time (can be even 15 minutes) until deactivation or re-activation of tenant is populated to the worker node.

When creating totally new organization with a newly created API, it is possible to run the API almost instantly at the worker. But if you disable the organization, the API will still run. It will take a long time until worker will report that the tenant is no longer active.

Same for re-activating a tenant. It will take a lot of time until worker will stop complaining about inactive organization and allow running the API.

Is there a configuration setup we need to change? Or is this expected behavior? Who should report to workers about organization changes in the absence of Hazelcast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tenant cache[1] which contains tenant information. The default TTL of the cache (and any cache) is 15 minutes. When you deactivate a tenant, this distributed cache is cleared using hazelcast. That is why you observe above when you disable hazelcast clustering.

Typically, in a production environment, it's very unlikely that you needing to activate and deactivate tenants very frequently. So I don't think 15min delay is a concerning problem.

However, if it really is, you have to keep Hazelcast clustering enabled. When you said you faced a lot of pain due to Hazelcast, I believe that's because of the distributed nature of these caches. As a solution, you may enable local cache as opposed to the distributed cache. Here, Hazelcast clustering is used only for the cache invalidation calls. That might work for you. (Disclaimer: I haven't tried this yet.)

For this, you need to set `ForceLocalCache` to `true` in `carbon.xml`

```
<Cache>
    <!-- Default cache timeout in minutes -->
    <DefaultCacheTimeout>15</DefaultCacheTimeout>
    <!-- Force all caches to act as local -->
    <ForceLocalCache>true</ForceLocalCache>
</Cache>
```

[1] https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/4.4.x/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/tenant/JDBCTenantManager.java#L303

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think you should explore more how to configure Hazelcast. Hazelcast is embedded in a lot of very highly used project stacks (JHipster, Atlassian, Apache Camel, SunGard, etc.) It’s very solid for doing what you want here, but it’s also highly configurable so you probably want to set it up according to your needs. If you just disable it, your removing all the clustered scalability that it brings. The configuration is just an XML file and you can find all the documentation here:

https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11.2/manual/html-single/index.html#understanding-configuration

It’s easy to figure out and definitely worth your time.